# Find the value.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $A$ & $B$ be the roots of the equation $ x^2 - 6x -2 = 0$  with $A > B$ .If $a_n = A^n - B^n$ for $n \ge 1$ ,then find the value of $\dfrac{a_{10} -2a_8}{2a_9}$.I have tried to use binomial theorem but it becomes messy & lengthy. Can anyone say how to solve it? The roots I have found out are $3 + \sqrt{11}$ and other is its conjugate.

Comment: Oh the answer is $3$.

Comment: $A^{10} = A^8 \cdot A^2 = (A^2)^4\cdot(6A+2) = (6A+2)^5$.  And apply this idea to $B^n$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a_n = A^n - B^n$ where $x = A$ and $x = B$ are the roots of $x^2-6x-2 = 0$ the sequence $a_n$ satisfies the recurrence relation $a_{n+2} - 6a_{n+1} -2a_n = 0$ for all integers $n \ge 0$.

Then, for $n = 8$ we get $a_{10} - 6a_9 - 2a_8 = 0$. So, $a_{10} - 2a_8 = 6a_9$, and thus, $\dfrac{a_{10} - 2a_8}{2a_9} = 3$.

Comment: @ JimmyK4542 :I have understood.Thanks but sir can u tell me what is recurrence relation?

Comment: Is A.P. a recurrence relation?

Comment: A recurrence relation is something that describes the $n$-th term of a sequence in terms of the preceding one(s).

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the recurrence relation, you already had all elements in you hands to show that $$a_n=c_1 \left(3-\sqrt{11}\right)^n+c_2 \left(3+\sqrt{11}\right)^n$$